# AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'tk'. Did you mean: 'tr'? PyQt5 Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to make canvas for PyQt5 GUI. For this, I've used TkInter's canvas property. So I created a new widget in Qt Designer for tkinter's canvas.

As you can see from the picture below, I created promoted class for QWidget to use Canvas.

[image]

Then I converted this GUI into python code.
When I try to run my GUI, I'm getting the error which is on the title.

That's normal code:

```py
from sympy import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import sympy
import sys
from tkinter import Canvas
from untitled import *



class canvastrying(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = canvastrying()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That's my GUI's code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(318, 325)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = Canvas(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 291, 231))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 318, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
from tkinter import Canvas
```

Can we use TkInter's canvas property in PyQt5? If we can, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Combining different gui toolkits are discouraged for various reasons, if they do not explicitly state they are built to work together. pick one and stick to it, otherwise you will need a lot of workarounds that you probably wont code or even find out about.

Comment: I just imported tkinter as tk. But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The canvas searches for the tcl interpreter that comes along with the instance of `tkinter.Tk`. What you trying to do wont work that easy and even if you get something together it probably will be errorprone  and not even work nice together as long as you not write source code for pyqt and tkinter.

Comment: Hmm. How can I add canvas to my GUI then? Can you help me about this?

Comment: You have begun with pyqt. Why dont you use [QPainter](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/bitmap-graphics/) ? I haven't worked much with pyqt despite some basics as I started with python. So I'm the wrong guy to help you with PyQt.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is to create mathematical operation with LaTeX. I need to a Canvas for this. Unfortunately PyQt5 doesn't contain anything about canvas.

Comment: @Deezwend No, you can ***NOT*** use tk widgets while using Qt. Different UI toolkits cannot play well together (actually, 99% of the times they cannot play together *at all*). If you need custom painting *and* want to use Qt, then you either use what Qt provides (through custom widgets and `paintEvent()` overrides using QPainter, or using the [graphics view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html)) or use an external library that can work *with* Qt, such as pyqtgraph (which is based on Qt bindings) or mathplotlib (which *can* use Qt bindings). In any case, remove any tk reference.

Comment: @musicamante I'll take a look at pyqtgraph and matplotlib. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: It's simply not going to be possible to effectively use any tk widget in a Qt-based application.